C# ASP.NET MVC View @IF(model.TimeStamp - DateTime.Now >= 12
I know this does not work but I was hoping to get something like this to work in my HTML View using ASP.NET MVC and C#.
My timestamp date (a database value) minus DateTime.Now greater than 12 hours then do this.
@foreach (var cont in contents)
{
    if (cont.IsArchive == null)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cont.ToolList_Text)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cont.GenericDropDownList_Text)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cont.Comment_Text)
            </td>

            @if (cont.TimeStamp - DateTime.Now >= 12)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => cont.TimeStamp)
                </td>
            }

            <td class="text-center">
                <div style="display: inline-flex;">
                    <button type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-info" id="edit" name="edit">Edit</button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <button type="submit" value="Archive" class="btn btn-danger" id="archive" name="archive">Archive</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}

I tried different ways to present the >= but still not working

Check TimeSpan class and TotalHours property.
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalhours?view=net-8.0
You can create a TimeSpan by substracting one date of the other.

Your solution does not work, as result of subtracting of two dates is not an integer (number) but a TimeSpan
So, as already suggested in comments, you need to verify TotalHours property to see if enough hours has elapsed between two DateTimes:
@if ((cont.TimeStamp - DateTime.Now).TotalHours >= 12)

